# Why is my parseFloat only allowing entries up to 1.00 to 999.00 to be posted back to the server

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

So I have an MVC form field

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Cost, new { placeholder = "Cost $XXX,XXX.XX", @class = "input-box-med" })
```

The field model.Cost is defined as :

```
 public Nullable<decimal> Cost { get; set; }
```

and when the user enters into the Textbox i am trying to cast the entry as Float to 2 decimal places, using this line.

```
// Currency Cast
        $('#Cost').on('blur', function () {
            const value = this.value.replace(/,/g, '');
            this.value = parseFloat(value).toLocaleString('en-US', {
                style: 'decimal',
                maximumFractionDigits: 2,
                minimumFractionDigits: 2
        });
        });
```

But when I post back only numbers entered from 1.00 to 999.00 are posted. Anything above that, is posted back as a null.

Here is an example of the input : 1000.00

[image]

Comment: Does your server freak out a number has a comma? My guess is the issue is with the code defining it as a number, but you set it as a string with a comma.

Comment: I suspect "," might be the culprit.  Please give an example of how you've typed in the number "1000", and confirm that particular example also came across as "null".  Please also try with/without commas, and tells us what happens.

Comment: As @epascarello pointed out, in that locale a number greater than 999 is likely to be formatted with a comma (`1,234.56`). Remember that `toLocaleString` returns a **string** (I know the name says it, but still).

Comment: @epascarello so, you are correct that is the issue, question is, how do I not return commas, or do I parse them out on return

Comment: You're calling `toLocaleString`, that's what it does. You take out the commas then add them right back in. [MDN #toLocaleString](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

Comment: Thanks all, I just changed the toLocaleString to "toFixed(2)" and that works for me

Comment: Noting that `toLocaleString` is fine if you set the `useGrouping` option to `false`.